# How to add script tag in head section to wordpress theme in cpanel?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, header

I was trying to add a script tag to wordpress theme which seems to be an easy task but it is not working out!

I editing header.php file under wp-content>themes>them_name - header.php

When I add script tag and try to reload the page I cannot see the script tag in header section.

I even cleared browser cache that were suggested on internet.

Please suggest me some options as I am not a wordpress expert.

**Thanks**

Comment: Two things: 1. make sure you're editing the right theme; 2. if you're using a caching plugin, you'll need to clear its cache for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I have only one theme so I am sure about theme. What is caching plugin. I don't have wordpress backend only wordpress theme is used on cpanel

Comment: If you don't have access to the WP Dashboard, then you'll want to check with your hosting about it.

Comment: It doesn't have WP Dashboard. only theme is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General**

The correct way to add scripts in WordPress is using `wp_enqueue_script()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Place the following code in functions.php:

```
function custom_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/script/name.js', array(), '1.0.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Note the 5th argument is `false`. This adds the script to the head rather than the end of the body.

**Your specific case:**

```
function custom_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('web-manager', 'domain.tld/js/web-manager.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Because your script requires the `async` and `data-key="abc123efg"` attributes you must also add this code to functions.php:

```
function custom_script_loader_tag($tag, $handle, $src) {
  if ('web-manager' === $handle) {
    $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" async src="' . $src . '" data-key="abc123efg"></script>';
  }
  return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'custom_script_loader_tag', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Buddy not working for me, I have added this piece of code in my function.php under theme directory. Thanks

Comment: Can you please paste the script you are trying to use in the original question.

Comment: <script async src="https://domain.tld/js/web-manager.min.js" data-key="abc123efg"></script>

Comment: Thanks waiting for your reply!